# Printing a square matrix in JS?

Tags: javascript, matrix, printing

I would like to print a

```js
function printSquareMatrix(size) {
  let mat = [size][size];
  for (let i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++) {
      mat[i][j] = '*';
    }
    mat[i][j] = '*';
  }
  return mat;
}


console.log(printSquareMatrix(3))
```

size*size square matrix with a JS function, but I receive an error upon execution. Where could be the problem?

Comment: `[size]` wraps the content of the variable `size` in an array. It _does not_ create an array with size `size`. Hence `[size][size]` doesn't make sense either.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, your declaration for a multi-dimensional array is not correct.

```js
function printSquareMatrix(size) {
  //     var mat = [[size][size]];
  var mat = Array.from(Array(size), () => new Array(size));
  for (var i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < size - 1; j++) {
      mat[i][j] = '*';
    }
    mat[i][j] = '*';
  }
  return mat;
}

console.log(printSquareMatrix(3))
```